# Can't install Office 2010 Beta on Server 2008 R2

Tags: microsoft-office, windows-server-2008

I've just tried to run the the install for Office 2010 Beta Home and Business on Server 2008 R2, and I get an error dialogue saying Office requires Windows 7, Vista SP1, or XP SP3.  I've tried running the install in compatability mode for all three with no luck.

Any suggestions?

ADDENDUM:  Initially I chose the "for home, small businesses, and school option", which yields Office Home and Business, which won't install on Server 2008 R2.  Choosing the "for enterprise and mid-sized businesses" yielded Office Professional Plus, which duly installed without issues.  The two intial options are slightly misleading, unless you read the fineprint, which actually includes "IT professionals" and developers in the Professional Plus package.

Comment: I somehow did manage to get Office 2010 installed, but I don't remember how.

Answer (score 2):

Server 2008 R2 is not listed as supported:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/evalcenter/ee390818.aspx

**Supported Operating Systems**:

- Windows XP with Service Pack (SP) 3 (32-bit)
- Windows Vista with SP1 (32-bit or 64-bit)
- Windows Server 2003 R2 (32-bit or 64-bit)
- Windows Server 2008 with SP2 (32-bit or 64-bit)
- Windows 7 (32-bit or 64-bit)

Comment: Quick trigger finger on the edit button. So quick that it didn't register as an edit and I can't remove my downvote

Answer (score 1):

That's old for Office 2010 (**not** beta):

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee624351.aspx

"Windows Server 2008 or later (32-bit or 64-bit)" is supported!